# getting the attribute values of XML node

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode

i am trying to get the values of the Arg1,2 and 3 attributes of the below XML...in the XML, there are 2 different values and the iteration through the code has been verified to iterate twice. but the same answer is displayed twice and i don't know what is missing...!!!

this is the XML:

```
-<event type="2VO">
-<properties>

<schedule endOffset="00:00:22:00" endType="Duration" startOffset="00:00:33:00" startType="-ParentEnd"/>

<event title="Pixel VO" reconcileKey="106251137"/>

+<mediaStream>
<media Arg8="" Arg7="" Arg6="" Arg5="" Arg4="" Arg3="O1T13810" Arg2="1910" Arg1="TON" RuleCode="2VO"/>

</properties>

</event>

-<event type="2VO">
-<properties>

<schedule endOffset="00:00:22:00" endType="Duration" startOffset="00:00:33:00" startType="-ParentEnd"/>

<event title="Pixel VO" reconcileKey="106251137"/>


+<mediaStream>
<media Arg8="" Arg7="" Arg6="" Arg5="" Arg4="" Arg3="O1T13810" Arg2="1932" Arg1="TUE" RuleCode="2VO"/>
</properties>
</event>
```

and the code is below here:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();

        xdoc.Load(@"C:\Users\namokhtar\Desktop\testxml.xml");

        foreach (XmlNode node in xdoc.SelectNodes("//event[@type='2VO']")) //or /CATALOG/CD

        {

            var x = node.SelectSingleNode("//@Arg1").Value;
            var y = node.SelectSingleNode("//@Arg2").Value;
            var z = node.SelectSingleNode("//@Arg3").Value;

            Console.WriteLine("The first parameter is: " + x);
            Console.WriteLine("The first parameter is: " + y);
            Console.WriteLine("The first parameter is: " + z);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: the output is only Arg1 =TON, Arg2 =1910, Arg3 = O1T13810 and repeated twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `"//"` in `"//@Arg1"` is telling it to look anywhere in the document not specifically the node you have selected so even thought you extract each `<event>` node, you then always get the first `"//@Arg1"` attribute value in the document.

Either use `".//@Arg1"` to tell it to search relative to the current node or be more specific with your `XPath` and use `"./properties/media/@Arg1"`

If it's any consolation, I don't find this `"//"` behaviour intuitive!